# Given the recurrence relation $a_n = −3a_{n−1} + 18a_{n−2}; n ≥ 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

> $a_n = −3a_{n−1} + 18a_{n−2}; n ≥ 2$
>
> Which of the following is a solution to this recurrence relation
>
> Alt 1) $3^{2n} + (−6)^n$
>
> Alt 2) $a_n = 5(−6)^n$
>
> Alt 3) $a_n = 3^n + 6^n$
>
> Alt 4) $a_n = 3^{n−2} + 2(−6)^{n+1}$

I've only learned how to find $a_n$ when I have initial values $a_0$ and $a_1$. I am not sure how to proceed without them. I've never seen a similar task before doing this task (its from an exam in 2015)

Comment: Well, what does the characteristic polynomial tell you?

Comment: Can you find the roots of the characteristic polynomial in the given options?

Comment: I did find that the characteristic polynomial would be $r^2-3r-18 = (r+6)(r-3)$ which would give me $a_n = C_1 * (-6)^n + C_2 * 3^n$, but I dont see what to do from here.

Comment: Well, which of those possible answers fit the form you discovered (correctly, I should say)?  (Hint:  unless I am mistaken, more than one of the possibilities works).

Comment: @Andreas That's nice! Now check all the options and see which one is of the form $C_1 (-6)^n + C_2 3^n$?

Comment: Okey, so Alt 2) is correct because we can set $C_1 = 0$ and $C_2 = 5$, Alt 4) is correct because we can set $C_1 = 1/9$ and $C_2 = -12$, Alt 1) isnt possible because we cant get $3^{2n}$ and Alt 3) isnt correct because we cant get $6^n$? (I know alt 2 and 4 is correct from the exam solution)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.